# Post Gre: Natural Full Join- How to replace null values in the int column with zeros?

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I am looking for a way to replace all the null vals, in the int field, with 0(zero) resulting from
NATURAL FULL JOIN on two tables. For example :

```
table1

 num | name
-----+------
   1 | a
   2 | b
   3 | c
```

and table2 :

```
 num | value
-----+-------
   1 | 40
   3 | 50
   5 | 60
```

( select * from  table1 natural full join table2 ) would result in :

```
num | name | value
----+------+---------
  1 | a    | 40
  2 | b    | 
  3 | c    | 50
  5 |      | 60
```

(4 rows)

I need to replace the empty place in the value column with 0. How can I do that?I am looking for a way to make it look like:

```
num | name | value
----+------+---------
  1 | a    | 40
  2 | b    | 0
  3 | c    | 50
  5 |      | 60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want to use something like this:

```
SELECT (...), COALESCE(intcolumn,0) FROM (...)
```